Why does Chrome default alerts have different behaviors when I want to open a local app?
I wanted to open a local app, so I used location.href = 'xxx://', but in different environments, the Google browser shows different alerts, one of these alerts has a checkbox for asking users if they want to always open this app, but another one doesn't have this checkbox.

How can I make them all don't show that checkbox?
